# Sorting a partial string date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The api returns data and does not have a year. There would never be a year for this application, just month and day. Also, some values do no not have a leading zero.

02/17
10/02
12/31
3/17

The data is not being sorted correctly. Should I convert this to a date or remove the leading 0 and / to sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get a good sort using [`localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with the `numeric` option:

```js
let dates = ['02/17', '10/02', '12/31', '3/17', '3/16', '3/01']
dates.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'en', {numeric:true}))
console.log(dates)
```